# Have you come across any reason for three levels of indirection?

Tags: language-agnostic, pointers, coding-style, indirection

Just flicking through one of my favourite books (Ellen Ullman's The Bug) and there is a small bit where one programmer confronts another over three levels of indirection:

```
***object_array = ***winarray;
```

I get the idea of double indirection - a way of passing a pointer into a function, and allowing it to point to an object created within the function.

But have you come across any reason to use three (or more) levels of indirection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure
4 dimensional arrays.
It doesn't take too much for an application for such an array either. Say some sort of lookup table. I've had lookup tables of 8 and more dimensions.

Answer (score 3):

As David Wheele said: "Any problem in computer science can be solved with another layer of indirection." You have almost certainly used three layers of indirection with a line like this:

```
int x = 3;
```

After all, the chip is indirecting memory access through two layers of L1 and L2 cache. And the OS is indirecting the memory access via virtual memory pages. And your C# compiler is indirecting the memory access via objects in a virtual machine. Sure, it doesn't come with a long line of asterixes, but that's because all of these indirections are abstracted with things liks a machine, an OS or a compiler.

Answer (score 2):

You're possibly running at 3 or more levels right now. Could be jQuery on javascript in a browser running in Windows on a Mac (or in a VM) via Remote Access running in ....

Or, from another perspective closer to your question's context, 3 levels is the most common artifact we have.

What's a pointer to a control in a container in a Window?

Answer (score 2):

No, I've never actually seen or used it (as far as I can recall, and at least not without sensible typedefs to make it less fubar), but I can contrive an example of what might be a [questionably] valid use:

```c
struct Foo{
    struct greater{
        bool operator()(Foo const *a, Foo const *b) const{
            return a->place > b->place ||
                   a->place == b->place && a->holder > b->holder;
        }
    };

    int place;
    int holder;
};

template<typename T, typename Comparer>
void Sort(T const *unorderedList, int count, T const ***orderedList, Comparer &cmp);

void UseOrderedList(Foo const **orderedList, int count);

int main(){
    Foo list[] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}};
    Foo const **orderedList;

    Sort(list, sizeof list / sizeof *list, &orderedList, Foo::greater());
    UseOrderedList(orderedList, sizeof list / sizeof *list);
    delete[] orderedList;
    return 0;
}

void UseOrderedList(Foo const **orderedList, int count){/*...*/}

template<typename T, typename Comparer>
void Sort(T const *unorderedList, int count, T const ***orderedList, Comparer &cmp){
    /*
     * The result array stores pointers to the items in the original array.
     * This way, the original array is unmodified, and the result array
     * doesn't create duplicate items.  This makes sense if the objects
     * are large and copying them would be slow (another argument against
     * in-place sorting), or if duplicating them violates some design
     * principle.
     */
    *orderedList = new const T*[count];

    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        (*orderedList)[i] = unorderedList + i;

    std::sort(*orderedList, &(*orderedList)[count], cmp);
}
```

I wouldn't actually do what I've done here.  It's just an example of how you could end up with three pointer levels.  I can't imagine you running into this kind of scenario very often, though.